# Secuencia oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Imaginemos que tengo una tabla usuarios cuyo max id es 100

```
select max(id) from usuarios;  => 100
```

y esta tabla usa la secuencia usuarios_id cuya last number es 52, cuando voy a crear un usuario me va a dar error porque creara un usuario con id 53 y ya existe, la solución es cambiar el last numebr de la secuencia a 101 para que no me de ese error.

Mi pregunta es acerca de como localizar en una database todas las tablas que puedan tener este error con una consulta, ¿ es posible?

Comment: A mi me paso hace una semana en wordpress y fue verificando los maximos tabla por tabla :p.. Ahora, supongo, querras alguna consulta mas general no? probaste algo?

Comment: si estamos habaldo de mas de 200 secuencias, aun estoy mirando que puedo probar

Comment: Supongo que una query al esquema que devuelva todas las secuencias, joineada a una query que devuelva el max por tabla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero te sirva esta consulta, te muestra listado de **tablas**, el **trigger** que dispara la secuencia, la **secuencia** y el **ultimo_valor** de la secuencia

```
    select tabs.table_name,
       trigs.trigger_name,
       seqs.sequence_name,
       seqs.last_number
from all_tables tabs
join all_triggers trigs
  on trigs.table_owner = tabs.owner
  and trigs.table_name = tabs.table_name
join all_dependencies deps
  on deps.owner = trigs.owner
  and deps.name = trigs.trigger_name
join all_sequences seqs
  on seqs.sequence_owner = deps.referenced_owner
  and seqs.sequence_name = deps.referenced_name

where tabs.owner = '<owner/propietario>';
```